# Выравнивание сложных элементов по базовой линии

Tags: html, css

У меня есть строка, в строке есть пачка элементов с разным фоном и разным размером текста, и стоит две задачи:

- растянуть фон этих элементов на всю высоту строки
- выровнять весь текст по baseline (причём из-за того, что снизу есть бордер, надо бы его сместить чуть ниже центра блока, чтобы казалось выровненным по центру)

То есть хочу что-то такое:

[image]

Изначально я сделал это тупо многочисленными паддингами, но потом стало нужно сделать адаптивную вёрстку с переменной высотой, и поддерживать паддинги это уже какой-то адок. Надо бы что-нибудь менее костыльное, чтобы высоту строчки можно было произвольно менять, и при этом ничего не разъезжалось.

По отдельности обе задачи решить — раз плюнуть. Можно растянуть блоки на всю высоту, но тогда съезжает выравнивание текста по вертикали. Можно выровнять текст по вертикали, но тогда фон нельзя будет растянуть. И вот что-то у меня не получается надумать, как решить всё и сразу.

Сниппет с выравниванием, но без фона:

```css
.myblock {
  background-color: #fdd;
  height: 44px;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #ccf;
}

.myitem {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background-color: #ddf;
}

.myitem1 {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.myitem2 {
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.myitem3 button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="myblock">
  <div class="myitem myitem1">Мелкие букофки</div>
  <div class="myitem myitem2">Бальщие букафки</div>
  <form class="myitem myitem3">
    <button>quit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Путём многочасовых размышлений нашёл-таки кое-какое решение своей проблемы. Суть такова:

- контейнеру задаём желаемые `font-size` и `line-height` — с помощью них устанавливается положение базовой линии.
- Внутрь пихаем `div`'ы высотой с контейнер. `font-size` и `line-height` наследуются, как и сама базовая линия. Фон устанавливается именно здесь и получается на всю высоту.
- Внутрь `div`'ов пихаем `span`'ы, задаём им нужный размер шрифта и сбрасываем `line-height`. Так как `span` является inline-элементом, базовая линия наследуется, и текст будет выровнен именно по ней независимо от установленного здесь размера шрифта.
- На этом можно было бы закончить, но я вспомнил, что мне нужна кнопка на всю высоту. Однако в кнопке текст выравнивается не по базовой линии, а по центру относительно высоты кнопки (как минимум в Firefox), из-за чего кнпока постоянно норовит куда-то уехать. Поэтому придётся запихать в кнопку два `span` друг в друга: первый будет inline-block и растягивается на всю высоту (аналогично `div` описанному выше) — он сбрасывает выравнивание текста по вертикали; а второй уже содержит нужный текст с нужным размером. Сама кнопка тоже растянута на всю высоту и имеет `vertical-align: top`, чтобы никуда не съезжать.

После этого можно произвольно менять высоту всей этой конструкции с помощью замены `height`, `line-height` и `font-size` у контейнера на нужные значения. (Проценты не проверял, но мне и не надо). Как-то так:

```css
.myblock {
  background-color: #fdd;
  height: 44px;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #ccf;
  font-size: 16px; /* подбирается методом тыка */
  line-height: 59px; /* height + border */
}

.myitem {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background-color: #ddf;
  height: inherit;
}

.myitem1 > span {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.25;
}

.myitem2 > span {
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 1.25;
}

.myitem3 button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  background-color: white;
  height: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.myitem3 button > span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: inherit;
}

.myitem3 button > span > span {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.25;
}
```

```html
<div class="myblock">
  <div class="myitem myitem1"><span>Мелкие букофки</span></div>
  <div class="myitem myitem2"><span>Бальщие букафки</span></div>
  <form class="myitem myitem3">
    <button><span><span>quit</span></span></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Однако всё-то выглядит костыльневатенько; если кто-то придумает решение получше, буду рад увидеть.

Answer (score 1):

Cделай через display: flex и не мучайся. Засунь текст в тег P и оберни еще одним дивом. Выровняй сначала дивы Myitem, а потом внутри них уже выровняй текст.

Comment: А можно пример?

Answer (score 0):

Блин начал делать как советовал, не получается :))

попробуй так:

```css
    .myblock {
      background-color: #fdd;
      height: 44px;
      border-bottom: 15px solid #ccf;
     overflow: hidden;
     margin-top: 10px;
      
    }
    .myitem {
        background-color: #ddf;
       display: flex;
       align-items: flex-end;
       
    }
    .myitem1 {
      height: 29px;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    .myitem2 {
      font-size: 28px;
     
    }
    .myitem3 button {
      height: 29px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
      font-family: inherit;
      font-size: 18px;
      background-color: white;
    }
    p {
      position: relative;
    }
    .myblock {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="myblock">
      <div class="myitem myitem1 ">
         <div>Мелкие букофки</div>
         </div>
      <div class="myitem myitem2">
        <div>Бальщие букафки</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <form class="myitem myitem3">
          <div>
            <button>quit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Это конечно костыли несусветные, но хоть что-то. Правда кнопку так и не отравнял. Может гуру css какой поможет.

Comment: Чё-то как-то ни одна цель не достигнута